# how to increment variable value in angular template

Tags: angular

I'm new to angular and want to increment value while printing as done in JAVA as follows:

```
<% int count=1; %>
<%=count++%> This is line with Text
<%=count++%> This is another line with different text
<%=count++%> This is line with different text
<%=count++%> This is last line
```

Comment: You shouldn't do things like this in template side of a component.

Comment: During the component's life cycle, everything within the template is going to be evaluated on every change detection. So my guess is, you actually _don't_ want to increase `count` this way. What is your actual objective?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this could be done only in html with some weird ngIf hacks, but that's not probably the way to go.

Instead you can declare an array in `*.component.ts` with your texts like this

```
lines = [
        'This is line with Text',
        'This is another line with different text',
        'This is line with different text',
        'This is last line',
    ];
```

and in `*.component.html` do an *ngFor

```
    <div *ngFor="let line of lines; let index = index">{{ index + 1 }}: {{line}}</div>
```

It will output:

```
<div>1: This is line with Text</div>
<div>2: This is another line with different text</div>
<div>3: This is line with different text</div>
<div>4: This is last line</div>
```